What is the cheapest way to retrieve a tag for the top commit in a shallow Git clone?
I have a shallow Git clone created with a command like:
git clone --depth 1 <repository-url>

This limits the clone to only the most recent commit. I want to determine if there is a tag associated with this top commit. Ideally, I want to avoid fetching additional data from the remote repository.
What I’ve Tried:

Using git describe:
When I run git describe --tags, it does not work for shallow clone
Fetching tags:
Running git fetch --tags followed by git describe --tags works, but defeats the purpose, it takes 2 minutes. That's too long.

Question:
What is the most efficient way to retrieve the tag for the top commit without fetching the full history or all tags?
Additional Context:
The shallow clone is a deliberate choice to minimize time and space (actually, this comes from a git submodule update with depth 1)

Try git ls-remote origin. The output requires further processing, of course.
